# MySQL Multiple Events in a trigger?

Tags: mysql

I'm using Sequelpro so im not sure if its an error with that but,

```
IF condition THEN
   DO STUFF;
ELSE IF THEN
   DO STUFF;

IF condition THEN
   DO STUFF;
END IF;
END IF;
```

Is this okay for syntax? I want to create multiple triggers for an update in a table but sequelpro says my version of MySql(5.6.1) does not support multiple triggers for an event.

Comment: Is that code block within a [`BEGIN ... END`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/begin-end.html) compound statement?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I use sequelpro and I don't have to do that manually

Comment: Well, `ELSEIF` requires a condition; perhaps you meant to use `ELSE`?  Aside from that and the missing `;` characters in the second conditional, I don't see a problem - why don't you try it and see?

Comment: There is a ; on the second statement - I did try to do it and got a syntax error. If i use an ELSE IF instead of an IF in the same IF block then I don't. It's just when I try to create the second block.

Comment: No, don't use `ELSE IF` - just `ELSE`.

Comment: Sorry I wrote it kind of hastily - fixed it with what I got sequel pro to accept. Is this the right way now?

Comment: You still have `ELSE IF` without a condition, which is syntactically incorrect.  Even if it was syntactically correct, it's no longer clear exactly what you're trying to do.  I suggest you show the complete `CREATE TRIGGER` command, in full, without trying to make an abstract example, and explain what it is that you expect the trigger to do.

Comment: In general:  `IF condition THEN <DO STUFF>; ELSEIF another_condition THEN <DO SOMETHING ELSE>; ELSE <DO OTHER STUFF>; ENDIF;`.  See [`IF` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/if.html).

Comment: What im asking I guess is can I have multiple IF blocks in one trigger, or does each IF block need its own trigger?

Comment: That's why one needs to enclose within a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement.